# Simple HTTP POST in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, http-post

I have a string that I need to POST in Windows Phone 8. It looks like this:

```
https://www.scoreoid.com/api/getPlayers?api_key=[apiKey]&game_id=[gameID]&response=xml&username=[username]&password=[password]
```

This string simply returns another string (that is formatted as XML that I parse later in my code).

I have yet to find a simple solution to this like in Windows 8.

**Edit:** Found the solution to my problem with an assist from rciovati and the [HttpClient](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) library.

Here's my simple code:

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri + "?" + post_data);
```

Comment: Do you have a _simple_ example of it used?

Comment: I did, but it seemed a lot more complicated than in Windows 8. If this is the extent of the help you can provide then I understand.

Comment: This is a GET, not a POST request

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using the new [Http Client Library](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) is quite easy:

```
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_key", "12345"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("game_id", "123456")
                    };

var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

You can find other informations about this library [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty useful blog post from [Andy Wigley](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/andy%20wigley/) about how to do Http networking on Windows Phone 8. The WinPhoneExtensions wrapper library he speaks of basically simulates the async/await model of network programming you can do in Win8.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/02/07/async-and-await-for-http-networking-on-windows-phone.aspx