# WIndows Phone: POST request doesn't work

Tags: post, windows-phone, http-post

i'm tryng to send the notification link and deviceID to a script on the web via a POST request. the problem is that the script receive only empty params.
i followed another example and my code looks like this:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("sending rquest");
            var URI = new Uri("http://www.jack-prove.comuv.com/update_link.php");
            wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);
            byte[] myDeviceID = (byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
            string ID = Convert.ToBase64String(myDeviceID);
            String par = "?link=" + e.ChannelUri.ToString() + "&ID=" + ID;
            MessageBox.Show(par);
            wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, "POST", par);
```

NOTE: the ID string contains a '=' charater could this be the problem? i've tried to call the script from the web and it works even with the '='

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138275/simple-http-post-in-windows-phone-8)

using the [Http client Library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)

```
using System.Net.Http;
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("link", e.ChannelUri.ToString()),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ID", ID)
};
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(URI, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```