# how use data like that to send request from windows phone

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-8, http-headers, webclient

how use data like that to send request from windows phone to http://rawafedtech.info/tafsir/stable-api/current/web/app_dev.php/dummy/login

```
{
"collectionId":"7cf8b655-b8e7-cf6b-94d8-3de0ff33aaef","id":"4ff2b7f2-4bfa-3407-59e9-666e3000bc2e",
"name":"login","description":"",
"url":"
http://rawafedtech.info/tafsir/stable-api/current/web/app_dev.php/dummy/login
","method":"POST","headers":"Content-Type: application/json\n",
"data":"{\"username\" : \"m.nasser\", \"password\" : \"123456\"}"
,"dataMode":"raw","timestamp":0,"version":2,"time":1433237635939
}
```

Comment: you mean to say you need to send an HTTP POST call? use HTTP client as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138275/simple-http-post-in-windows-phone-8)